# Выбор правильного падежа

Tags: грамотная-речь, падежи, управление

В каком падеже надо поставить слово "миллион" в этом предложении?
*В прошлом году медцентр оказал медпомощь более миллиона пациентов.*

Answer (score 1):

**В прошлом году медцентр оказал медпомощь более чем миллиону пациентов.**
Либо так:
**В прошлом году более миллиона пациентов получили медпомощь медцентра.**

Comment: Оба варианта хороши. Благодарю.

Answer (score 1):

Оба варианта, конечно же, хороши. Но не совсем.
Тут у нас в чистом виде *масло масляное* образовалось: **мед**центр, **мед**помощь и [пациент](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82) (лицо, обратившееся за медицинской помощью или находящееся под медицинским наблюдением).

Немного о конструкции [*более чем*](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?id=58_68&layout=item).

> Однако при отсутствии сравниваемых понятий слова «(не) более / больше чем» образуют с последующими словами неразложимое сочетание (единый член предложения), не требующее постановки знаков препинания. Как правило, в этом случае после слов «(не) более / больше чем» следует количественно-именное сочетание (счетный оборот) или название единицы измерения (*час, грамм, километр* и т. п.).
> *Таким образом тайна была сохранена **более чем** полудюжиною заговорщиков.* А. Пушкин, Метель. *Водка была горькая, разведенная, по случаю праздника, водой **более чем** на три четверти.* В. Короленко, Сон Макара.

Падеж оборота выбирается по управлению глагола:
сохранена (кем? Т. п.) [более чем] полудюжиною заговорщиков;
оказал (кому? Д. п.) [более чем] миллиону пациентов.

*В прошлом году медцентр оказал помощь более чем миллиону пациентов.*

За полтора года работы Комиссии в ее новом качестве удалось добиться изменения законодательства о гражданстве, что **облегчило** получение гражданства **более чем миллиону человек**... [Э. А. Памфилова. Выступление на 60-й сессии Комиссии ООН по правам человека // «Дипломатический вестник», 2004.05.25]

Comment: Спасибо! Ваша информация была очень полезна.

Comment: Вопрос был про падежи, а не про то, имеется ли речевая избыточность.